# Whats a site or app where I can extract a public key just by typing in a private key?

Tags: wallet, private-key

I read that you are able to extract the public key address from a private key address. Is there a website or app that can do such a thing? I just want to be able to see if I can make up my own private key.

Answer (score 2):

The [BrainWallet](http://brainwallet.org) website does the trick.

Comment: so i just paste my private key in the textbox? but does it have to be a specific format because it doesnt seem like I can just type anything in there even though it meets the length requirements.

Comment: Yeah a private key must be of a specific format. Do some reading on ECDSA, I don't know the format by heart. If you want to be able to enter just any line of text as a private key, you should use the passphrase field of BrainWallet.

Comment: So I can just create a passphrase which gets converted into a bitcoin wallet address? Now I would just have to remember that to retrieve the address and private key? Like this: http://prntscr.com/2f6z5i ??

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose of a brain wallet. Keep in mind that everyone can try those passphrase, so make sure you use a very strong one for it.